# Saving important value

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase

Imagine my app as a list manager. On first launch, you have one empty list. You can add as many stuff in it as you want for free, but if you want more lists, you have to buy an In App Purchase. I have two types of IAP : you can purchase lists one-by-one, as a consumable item (which you can't transfer to another device), or purchase an "unlimited lists" item (non-consumable), which lets you add as many lists as you want, and all yourd devices benefit from it. Note that I will probably disable the first one if you bought the second one.

To handle this, I use a global var through my app. The variable represents the maximum number of lists you are allowed to have. At first launch, the value is "1". If you buy a single list, the value becomes "2", and so on. If you buy the "unlimited pack", the value is set to "-1". So if your current number of lists is less than what you're allowed to have, you can add new lists.

I need to save this value locally somehow, so for example if the user bought the unlimited pack, he can keep adding lists when he comes back in the app.

What is the best way to securely save this value ? I usually use `NSUserDefaults` but I'm not sure one can't change the values manually. Also, storing them online is not an option as you can use the app offline.

If you think my way of handling the IAP with this variable is not the right one, please don't hesitate to tell me how you'd do it. Thanks.

Comment: Check what you plan is allowed by Apple. Use the keychain.

Comment: @Wain : what do you think could not be allowed by Apple ?

Comment: I'm not convinced that your use of consumable will be acceptable (or a good idea to offer to users from a UX point of view).

Comment: @Wain I see what you mean, my problem is that how I see the use of the app is 60% will use one list, 30% will need two lists, and 10% will need more. How would you handle this regarding the types of IAP ?

Comment: I'd offer 2 lists and infinite lists as your 2 IAP options, both of which are restorable and available on all devices. Simpler for users and for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it into iOS Keychain.

There is a library that helps dealing with it: https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/tree/master/Security

So, to save number of lists, you'll use it like

```
[STKeychain storeUsername:@"lists" 
              andPassword:@"1" 
           forServiceName:@"my_super_app" 
           updateExisting:YES 
                    error:&error];
```

To retrieve:

```
[STKeychain getPasswordForUsername:@"lists" 
                    andServiceName:@"my_super_app" 
                             error:&error];
```

Comment: The library seams a bit old (2 years or so), and iOS keychain has changed quite a bit in the latest iOSs hasn't it ?

Comment: According to the revision history of Keychain Services Programming Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/revisionHistory/revisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH206-TPXREF101) There were no significant changes in Keychain API for a very long time

Comment: Great I'll go with this then ! Thanks a lot !